# Generador de secuencia python

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

me gustaria hacer un generador de secuencia, no se si es asi como se llama, pero que mejor con ejemplo. Dado el siguiente string: `caracteres = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,:;!?"\'()[]{}|/\*<>%#&@$_+-%'`
luego una palabra como `aaa`, la ultima letra pase por todo el string, luego pase al anterior a ese, cambie por el segundo elemento de la lista, vuelva al primero, que pase por ese devuelta toda la lista y asi sucesivamente.
Ej: `aaa, aab, aac, aad... aa%, aba, abb, abc... ab%, aca`
Dos cosas adicionales:

1. Lo estoy haciendo en colab, para que la pc no explote
2. Chat GPT me quiso ayudar y no lo hizo bien. A continuacion muestro que hizo:

```
# Definir el string de símbolos
simbolos = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,:;!?"\'()[]{}|/\\*<>%#&@$_+-%'  

# Palabra inicial
palabra = 'aa'  # Palabra inicial

# Bucle para cambiar las letras
while True:
    print(palabra)
    
    # Verificar si la palabra alcanzó %%
    if palabra == '%%':
        break
    
    # Cambiar la última letra por la siguiente en simbolos
    nueva_palabra = ''
    for letra in palabra:
        indice = simbolos.index(letra)
        siguiente_indice = (indice + 1) % len(simbolos)
        nueva_palabra += simbolos[siguiente_indice]
    
    # Si la primera letra llega a %, reiniciamos a 'a' y avanzamos la segunda letra
    if nueva_palabra[0] == '%':
        nueva_palabra = 'a' + nueva_palabra[1]
    
    palabra = nueva_palabra
```

Gracias, espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma estándar de generar secuencias es pensar en cada elemento de la secuencia como un valor en base X, donde X es la cantidad de símbolos disponibles.

En el problema, la base es 91, igual al número de símbolos. Cada número en base 91 se escribe usando los símbolos entregados.

La secuencia se genera iterando desde 0 en adelante. En cada iteración obtendré la representación de ese valor en base 91 y reemplazare los últimos caracteres de la palabra original.

El proceso sigue hasta que la representación del valor iterado supera el largo de la palabra:

```
caracteres = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,:;!?"\'()[]{}|/*<>%#&@$_+-%'

def secuencia(palabra: str):

    base = len(caracteres) # Base numérica X
    largo = len(palabra)
    i = 0
    while True:
        salida = []
        valor = i
        #   Generar la representación en base X de i.
        while valor:
            resto = valor % base
            valor = valor // base
            salida.append(caracteres[resto])
        #   Reemplazar ultimas letras por representación de i en base X.
        resultado = palabra[:largo - len(salida)] + ''.join(salida[::-1])

        if len(resultado) > largo:
            return

        print(resultado)
        i += 1


secuencia("aaa")
```

produce:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aad
...
%%_
%%+
%%-
%%%

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio